# Star crossed lovers

Tags: riddle

A love note, found at the scene of their remains, from one to the other:

> My love,
>
> Complete me. Dive into me. Stay until you're soft. Just crumble to
> pieces. We're the gift for the giver, the monster's delight. I see past your eyes and into your soul. But our love, as sweet as it is, will never survive. You're Romeo; I'm Juliet, doomed from the moment we met. We'll never keep her promise.

Who were these lovers?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"Partial" answer?

> Cookies and Milk

Complete me. Dive into me. Stay until you're soft. Just crumble to pieces

> Not complete without both! You dunk the cookie, it "dives" into the milk, and it gets soft and if you leave it long enough it crumbles apart.

We're the gift for the giver

> People leave out cookies and milk for Santa Claus, the ultimate giver

The monster's delight

> the cookie monster

I see past your eyes and into your soul

> "Past your eyes" = "pasturise"

But our love, as sweet as it is, will never survive

> Cookies and milk are sweet, and who doesn't eat them all? Then they're gone

You're Romeo; I'm Juliet, doomed from the moment we met. We'll never keep her promise.

> I don't know this part (OP: Girls Scouts famously sell cookies and their creed is the "Girl Scout Promise.")

Comment: Yes :) For the eyes/soul clue, it may help to say it out loud. There is a relevant word that sounds out. For the last clue, Romeo/Juliet just relates to your previous reason that them getting together causes their demise. The promise is related to one of these pairings' most prolific distributors (USA).

Answer (score 3):

I know you already have an answer in mind and one selected, but I felt that this also fit.

> A person and some candy

Complete me. Dive into me. Stay until you're soft. Just crumble to pieces

> It can complete someone's cravings. You "dive" into food you enjoy. Some candies are soft or crumbly.

We're the gift for the giver

> Candies can be used as gifts, like on Valentine's day.

The monster's delight

> Snickers, "you're not you when you're hungry."

I see past your eyes and into your soul

> Chocolate is often a deep craving for people but they try to suppress the unhealthy urges.

But our love, as sweet as it is, will never survive

> Candy can be sweet, but you eating it means it won't last long.

You're Romeo; I'm Juliet, doomed from the moment we met. We'll never keep her promise.

> The candy is doomed to be eaten from the moment you get it.

Comment: Definitely within the same idea, but without being as well-fitting for the giver/monster hints.

Comment: Cookies and milk definitely fit the giver better, and they're more of a duo, just liked some of these, especially the Snickers quote ;)

Comment: Milk is also "past your eyes" which was a fun pun :)